# Uncaught ReferenceError: Seed is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently reading fullstack vue and I dont understand why Im getting  this error on this example.

```
window.Seed = (function () {
    const submissions = [ 
        { 
            id: 1, 
            title: 'Yellow Pail', 
            description: 'On-demand sand castle construction expertise.', 
            url: '#', 
            votes: 16, 
            avatar: '../public/images/avatars/daniel.jpg', 
            submissionImage: '../public/images/submissions/image-yellow.png', 
        } 

    ];
    }());
```

this is where the seed function is. Basically its just the database we are using in the example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.5.3/css/bulma.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css"> 
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/styles.css" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"> 
            <h2 class="title has-text-centered dividing-header">UpVote!</h2>
            <div class="section"> 
                <article class="media"> 
                    <figure class="media-left"> 
                        <img class="image is-64x64" v-bind:src="submissions[0].submissionImage"> 
                    </figure> 
                    <div class="media-content"> 
                        <div class="content"> 
                            <p> 
                                <strong> 
                                    <a v-bind:href="submissions[0].url" class="has-text-info">
                                     {{ submissions[0].title }} 
                                    </a> 
                                    <span class="tag is-small">
                                        #{{ submissions[0].id }}
                                    </span> 
                                </strong> 
                                <br> 
                                {{ submissions[0].description }} 
                                <br> 
                                <small class="is-size-7"> Submitted by: 
                                    <img class="image is-24x24" v-bind:src="submissions[0].avatar"> 
                                </small> 
                            </p> 
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="media-right"> 
                        <span class="icon is-small"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> 
                            <strong class="has-text-info">{{ submissions[0].votes }}
                            </strong> 
                        </span> 
                    </div> 
                </article> 
            </div>    
        </div>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <script src="./main.js"></script> 
         <script src="./seed.js"></script> 

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my index.html

```
new Vue({
         el: '#app',
         data: { 
            submissions: Seed.submissions 
         }
         });
```

and finally here is my main.js which role is to connect the index.html and the seed.js. But its not working

Comment: Your loading seed after main,

Comment: thank you, you're right but i got another error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submissions' of undefined"

Comment: ... and your IIFE does not return anything. `window.Seed` is thus `undefined`.

Comment: thank you so much i was missing "return { submissions: submissions };" it wasn't written in the book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that you should try:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
window.Seed = (function () {
    const submissions = [ 
        { 
            id: 1, 
            title: 'Yellow Pail', 
            description: 'On-demand sand castle construction expertise.', 
            url: '#', 
            votes: 16, 
            avatar: '../public/images/avatars/daniel.jpg', 
            submissionImage: '../public/images/submissions/image-yellow.png', 
        } 

    ];
   window.Seed.submissions = submissions;
    }());
})
```

And in your index.html file add this code:

```
new Vue({
         el: '#app',
         data: { 
            submissions: window.Seed.submissions 
         }
         });
```

Using this would solve your problem.
The issue with you code was that `window.Seed had the self-invoking function`that does not return anything so you can set the property of submissions into the window.Seed object. Hope it helps

Comment: @YvanRoan if it works you can approve the answer for the same.

Comment: I did but my reputation points are too low so you can’t see, sorry.

Comment: @YvanRoan you have to click in the tick present

Comment: Oh my bad I didn’t look at it